# Wordpress - Drop Down Menu auto select using button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

Hey guys I'm wondering if the below is possible in WordPress based on the scenario, also these are the plugins I'm using **Contact Form 7** and **Contact Form 7 Conditional Fields**:

I have 3 pages:-
**Page A** which has a list of products.
**Page B** which is a single product that would've been clicked on from **Page A** and also has a button that leads to **Page C**.
**Page C** which is basically a contact page with 2 conditional field groups where the user can either select "General Question" or "Product Inquiry". After one of the two options is selected, a set of fields will appear respective to the option selected. When the "Product Inquiry" in particular is selected, another drop-down list will appear which has the list of products in which the user will choose which product they're inquiring about.

So what I want to know is if there is a way that when the user clicks on the button from Page B and it then goes to Page C, how can it automatically choose the "Product Inquiry" drop-down option and then select the same product from which they came on the list of products drop-down that has now appeared? I want to lessen the manual work for the user.

I'm thinking maybe the button could work like some sort of accordion select where you just set the #id of the accordion you want to open in the hyperlink/url.

Any thoughts would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a `$_GET`. Let's say you have products: "Ball", "Bat", and "Gloves". Here's an example:

```
<a href="/form?menu-10=Ball"><button>Click here for ball</button></a>
<a href="/form?menu-10=Bat"><button>Click here for bat</button></a>
<a href="/form?menu-10=Gloves"><button>Click here for gloves</button></a>
```

Then in your Contact Form 7 form settings, you would have something like this:

```
[select* menu-10 default:get "Ball" "Bat" "Gloves"]
```

You would obviously change `menu-10` to whatever your menu ID is.

Comment: I'll try this out.